# Plot Even Piecewise function

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise

Is it possible in *Mathematica* to plot an even piecewise function like:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 3t ,  0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
      3t  + 6 ,  \frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \pi \end{cases}$

which has a period of $2\pi$ . I can plot the function as is like so:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{3t, 0 <= t <= π/2}, {3t + 6, π/2 <= t <= π}}], {t, 0, π}]
```

but I can't seem to get it to repeat or show evenly.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/63463).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concepts of "even" and "periodic" relate to the action of the one-dimensional analogs of [wallpaper groups](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WallpaperGroups.html).  "Even" means that the function is invariant under reflection about the origin, $t \to -t$, and "periodic" means it is invariant under translation by some period $p$, $t \to t+p$.

The function $f$ in the question has been declared over a *fundamental domain*, in this case the interval from $0$ to $\pi$.  To extend it to a function of the reals, for each $t$ not in this domain we need to find a group element $g$ (generated by the reflection and translation) for which the application of $g$ to $t$ yields a number $t^{(g)}$ in the fundamental domain.  We then define $f(t)$ to equal $f(t^{(g)})$.

Although this may sound abstract, it translates to a highly general, efficient, almost mindless computational method.  For one-dimensional groups, we can figure out $t^{(g)}$ by means of the `Mod` function (to implement the translation) and the `Abs` function (to implement the reflection).  It is convenient first to translate $t$ into a domain that is as close to the origin as possible: do this by offsetting `Mod` by half the period, as in `Mod[t, 2 Pi, -Pi]`.  The result now lies in the symmetrical interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ around $0$.  Taking the absolute value assures the result is positive, where $f$ can be applied.  Whence, after defining `f` as in the question, merely declare its extension `g` by following this recipe:

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{3 t, 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, {3 t + 6, Pi/2 <= t < Pi}}, Null];
g[t_] := f[Abs[Mod[t, 2 Pi, -Pi]]];
Plot[{g[t], f[t]}, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Thick}]
```

[image: Plot of g and f]

Visually, it is clear that $g$ (the blue graph) is even and periodic and agrees with $f$ (the red graph) on the fundamental domain $[0, \pi)$ where $f$ is defined.

Comment: Deleted my answer. It wasn't periodic at all! :D

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `Mod` function to sample the area you have the function defined over at other parts of the $x$-axis if that's what you're aiming for.

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{3 t, 0 <= t <= π/2}, {3 t + 6, π/2 <= t <= π}}]
Plot[f[Mod[t, π]], {t, -π, 2 π}]
```

[image: plot of function]

Comment: I notice that your avatar is changing with your IP address.  If you set an email address in your profile it will remain constant.  It doesn't have to be a real one, and in fact you can try several until you find one that creates an avatar pattern that you like.  If you use a fake one it's better to make it obviously fake so that an admin doesn't try to use it to contact you.

Comment: This graph does not depict an "even ... function ... which has period of $2\pi$": it is not even and its period is only $\pi$.