# Graph a Function with general conditions

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plot Even Piecewise function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13513/plot-even-piecewise-function)

Based on Howell's Principles of Fourier Analysis, I found a function

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
   \sqrt{|x|} & \text{ if }-\pi < x < \pi \\
   f(x-2\pi) & \text{ in general }
\end{cases}
$

and the author seem to be able to produce a graph with Maple that is like a bun and continuous. Now my question is how can I produce the same graph of this type in Mathematica. I am aware that I can use the piecewise function but the second condition say "in general" and hence I am lost. Please give advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[Abs[x]], -Pi < x < Pi}, {f[x - 2 Pi], 
    x > Pi}, {f[x + 2 Pi], x < -Pi}}]

Plot[f[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: plot]

So what I did here is to realize the recursive nature of the definition for `f[x]` outside the central interval, but make sure that values outside are transported back into the middle by distinguishing the positive and negative side.

**Edit**

As pointed out by whuber in the comment, the *mathematical* statement in your original case distinction is best translated into a different *computational* approach that avoids the recursive self-reference to `f`. The goal of translating `x` back to the "fundamental" interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ can be achieved by replacing `x` with `Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi]` so that without any restriction on `x` we can write

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[Abs[Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi]]]
```

leading to the same plot as above.

Comment: Perfect!! I didn't know I can do like this. Thanks Jens!

Comment: Cleaner and (far) more efficient is `f[x_] := Sqrt[Abs[Mod[x, 2 Pi, -Pi]]]`, because if there is any possibility `f` would be applied to largish numbers, the recursive solution doesn't work.  (E.g, try `Plot[f[x], {x, 10^6 - 20, 10^6}]`.)

Comment: Oh this is special. I have never seen this before, whuber. THanks.

Comment: @whuber That's actually what I wanted to write first, believe it or not. But then something told me I should  stay closer to the question... Anyway, you're right of course.

Comment: There would be no harm in including both solutions in your answer :-).

Comment: @Sandra You can put pretty much any function you want in Plot. Example: `Plot[RandomReal[], {x, 0, 10}]` Of course, this doesn't mean any function can be manipulated algebraically by Mathematica in general.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, if you want to do other things with f, the `Piecewise` solutions by @Jens is probably best. But just note you can do it with three separate clauses:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[Abs[x]] /; -Pi< x <= Pi
f[x_] := f[x -2Pi] /; Pi < x
f[x_] := f[x + 2Pi] /; x <= -Pi
Plot[f[x], {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```